# gson json parser: value without key

Tags: java, json, gson

I want to parse a json structure like this:

```
{"response":
    {
    "arr1":[count,{...}],
    "arr2":[count,{...}]
    }
}
```

Everything is ok if count have key "count" (for example). But the key is blank. Is it any way to map this structure and manually retrive only this value or i need to parse all of this json myself without gson ?

**UPDATED**

Here is a valid json (checked with http://jsonlint.com/)

```
{
    "response": {
        "arr1": [
            615,
            {
                "body": "hi",
                "title": "Re(2):  ..."
            },
            {
                "body": "hello",
                "title": "Re(23):  ..."
            }
        ],
        "arr2": [
            132,
            {
                "body": "hi",
                "title": "Re(2):  ..."
            },
            {
                "body": "hello",
                "title": "Re(23):  ..."
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: What's inside `{...}`? As it is, this is not valid JSON syntax so it is unlikely that you will be able to do anything

Comment: in {} there is a valid json, for example "arr1":[123,{"body":"somebody", title:"sometitle"},{"body":"somebody", title:"sometitle"}]....   Online json checkers said that everything is ok

Comment: Strings needs to be enclosed in double quotes, so currently this is not valid. Edit your question and post valid JSon for your JSon structure and we'll take it from there.

Comment: ok, i've paste the sample of the valid JSON

Comment: When is the key "count" actually just nothing, should you not return a 0 instead of a blank key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to parse arbitrary collections you should read [Serializing and Deserializing Collection with Objects of Arbitrary Types](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Collection-with-Objects-of-Arbitrary-Types) and look at the example code [example code](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/extras/examples/rawcollections/RawCollectionsExample.java).