# Gson parsing string that has no key-value pairs

Tags: java, string, parsing, gson

I'm trying to parse a string with Gson library but without success. Here is my string:

```
[["-1.816513","52.5487566"],["-1.8164913","52.548824"]]
```

the problem in this example is that there are no key-value pairs. I looked at other examples but all of them had key-value pairs and didn't look like my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034643/parsing-json-feeds-with-google-gson?rq=1

Comment: I updated my question about dublication

Comment: I think [this may be relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10800508/). But I agree with OP, this is not a candidate for closing as duplicate, at least not for the original link. This is a separate problem with a very different solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution to parse a list of list of strings.

```
package stackoverflow.answers;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class GsonTest {

  public static void main(String[] arg) {

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonOutput = "[[\"-1.816513\",\"52.5487566\"],[\"-1.8164913\",\"52.548824\"]]";
    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<List<String>>>() {}.getType();
    List<List<String>> strings = (List<List<String>>) gson.fromJson(jsonOutput, listType);
    for(List<String> inner: strings){
      for(String s: inner){
        System.out.println(s);
      }
    }

  }
}
```

But since values can be "thinked" also a doubles, you can parse them directly changing type into solution:

```
package stackoverflow.answers;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class GsonTest {

  public static void main(String[] arg) {

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonOutput = "[[\"-1.816513\",\"52.5487566\"],[\"-1.8164913\",\"52.548824\"]]";
    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<List<Double>>>() {}.getType();
    List<List<Double>> numbers = (List<List<Double>>) gson.fromJson(jsonOutput, listType);
    for(List<Double> inner: numbers){
      for(Double d: inner){
        System.out.println(d);
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Not important in the context, but for future references: Java 7, Gson 2.2.4

Comment: typed parsing, nice => +1

Comment: Thanks trapo. after using String instead of Double type it worked.

Comment: They seemed doubles to me ;).

Comment: :) ofcourse they should have, but in this form it gives this error : Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 3

Comment: Just since I'm curious. Are you using same Gson version as me? Moreover, are you sure that you do not have extra " ?

Comment: Version is the same but there is much more :) sory have made a mistake now your code is working perfectly

Answer (score 1):

One solution, with raw types:

```
package com.stackoverflow.so18525283;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import java.util.List;

public class App {

    private static final String INPUT = "[[\"-1.816513\",\"52.5487566\"],[\"-1.8164913\",\"52.548824\"]]";

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        final List<?> fromJson = gson.fromJson(INPUT, List.class);
        if (fromJson != null && fromJson.size() > 0 && fromJson.get(0) instanceof List) {
            System.out.println(((List<?>) fromJson.get(0)).get(0)); // this is a String
        }
    }
}
```

Another solution is to recreate a valid JSON object, same `App` as below but with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    final Foo fromJson = gson.fromJson("{ data: " + INPUT + "}", Foo.class);
    // TODO: check for null
    System.out.println(fromJson.data.get(0).get(0)); // this is a Double
}

private static class Foo {
    List<List<Double>> data;
}
```

Comment: "package com.stackoverflow.so18525283;" nice! I take the liberty of copying your package naming style :)